# React native card (native base) onPress doesn't work

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I want to display cards with news from a JSON file.
Getting the JSON works fine, but I want to add a onPress event, so I can click the card and navigate to the article.

My card view:

```
<Card>
  <CardItem button onPress={this._OnButtonPress(news.id)}>
    <Left>
      <Body>
        <Text style={styles.cardText}>{news.title}</Text>
      </Body>
    </Left>
  </CardItem>
  <CardItem>
    <Left>
        <Icon style={styles.icon} name="chatbubbles" />
        <Text>{news.comments} comments</Text>
    </Left>
    <Right>
      <Text>{news.published}</Text>
    </Right>
  </CardItem>
</Card>
```

I am trying to pass a variable to the onButtonPress() function

```
_OnButtonPress(newsID) {
  Alert.alert(newsID.toString());
}
```

To test the onPress event, all I did is alert the parameter.

[I don't see anything wrong, but still I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp1of.png)

Does anyone know how I can fix this and what Im doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

**Update**

My updated class:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Image,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Left,
  Right,
  Button,
  Card,
  CardItem,
  Icon,
  Body,
  Content,
  Logo
} from 'native-base';

import styles from "./styles";

const logo = require("../../../img/f1today.png");

var REQUEST_URL = 'http://v2.first-place.nl/test/news.json';

class News extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._OnButtonPress = this._OnButtonPress.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
    };
  }

  _OnButtonPress(newsID) {
    Alert.alert(newsID.toString());
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.articles),
          loaded: true,
        });
      })
      .done();
  }

  render() {

    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Header
          style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff" }}
          androidStatusBarColor="#f05423"
          iosBarStyle="light-content">

        <Left>
          <Button
            transparent
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}
          >
            <Icon name="ios-menu" style={{color: 'black'}} />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body> 
          <Image source={logo} style={styles.headerLogo} />
        </Body>
        <Right />

      </Header>

      <Content padder>

        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderNews}
          style={styles.listView}
        />

      </Content>
    </Container>
    );
  }

  renderLoadingView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.loading}>
        <Text>
          Loading news...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderNews(news) {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardItem button onPress={()=> this._OnButtonPress(news.id)}>
          <Left>
            <Body>
              <Text style={styles.cardText}>{news.title}</Text>
            </Body>
          </Left>
        </CardItem>
        <CardItem>
          <Left>
              <Icon style={styles.icon} name="chatbubbles" />
              <Text>{news.comments} comments</Text>
          </Left>
          <Right>
            <Text>{news.published}</Text>
          </Right>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default News;
```

Comment: It is discouraged to pass parameters to a function inside the `render` method since it'll render it every time the component refresh... unless, of course, it is completely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the method cannot access the scope of the view. Right now you have your renderNews method defined this way:

```
renderNews(news) { }
```

If you declare your method this way you will not have this available on your method and as "this" is undefined, all the methods will trigger an error because you are trying to access to "undefined.methodName()". Having said that, you should "tie" the context to your method declaring it this way:

```
renderNews = (news) => { }
```

Now you have the context attached to the method and "this" is accesible inside.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer

Answer (score 12):

You should wrap your CardItem with TouchableOpacity or any other Touchable item. And give onPress function to that Touchable item.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => //your function}
    <CardItem>
    </CardItem>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**Note:** Make sure you use the `<TouchableOpacity>` component associated with the `react-native` package rather than the `react-native-gesture-handler` package. Visual Studio Code editor may auto-import from `react-native-gesture-handler` which does not work in this particular use case.

Correct Package:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
```

Incorrect Package:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Comment: ah sorry, didn't realize that you are giving onPress function to CardItem. so you should wrap  your CardItem with Touch item. it should look like in my answer which is i have edited.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem was the function not being found outside the card

Answer (score 4):

For me i left the button={true} prop off, when i added it works. See example below.

```
  <CardItem 
       button={true}
       onPress={() => {this.cardSelected(item.name)}}
       style={{paddingTop:0,paddingBottom:0,paddingLeft:0,paddingRight:0}}>
      <Image  source={item.img} style={{flex:1,resizeMode: 'cover',height: 175}} />
      <Text style={styles.cardheading}>{item.name}</Text>
        <Image source={cardline} style={styles.cardline}/>
        <Text style={styles.cardtext}> {item.text}</Text>

      </CardItem>
```

Comment: This one is more into native base library thing. Unlike TouchableOpacity its not affecting my other Views. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind this function. Write the following code inside your constructor function:

```
this._OnButtonPress = this._OnButtonPress.bind(this);
```

Also, changed the onPress as following:

```
onPress={()=> this._OnButtonPress(news.title)}
```

Finally, i could see the onPress been written on the component. Rather you should define/write it inside that container.

Comment: Now, when I click the CardItem I get the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbAbA.png

Comment: Did you updated the constructor function ? by writing the bind ?

Comment: Tel me one thing, you have a component. You should write the onPress inside the component. Not here.

Comment: Yes, I added this._OnButtonPress = this._OnButtonPress.bind(this); to the constructor

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Update the onPress event.

Comment: I already updated the opPress event, the image I sent is the error

Comment: You getting error om runtime, or after the onPress event ?